# Preview function no longer seems to work

Tags: cognito-forms

I am attempting to preview a form I am currently building and am unable to do so. Previously, before the new updates to the system, I was able to preview the form I am creating as I go along. However, currently, only the title of the form appears. I would really like to see how the columns/rows and headings look before I publish the form, as well as do the test the calculation fields. I have tried different browsers as well as different computers and am still having the same issues.

As a remedy for the issue above is being worked on, am I able to publish my form to see what it looks like as well as make sure the formulas are working?

If I publish the form and do that, will I be able to go back and make changes?

Answer (score 1):

I work for support for Cognito Forms.  Please file a support request and we will see exactly why your form is not showing up.  For the question itself -- yes, you can publish as many times as you wish and make changes at will.